# Cannot GET data via Django + ReactJS framework

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django + ReactJS and I'm having trouble getting data from my Django model.

I'm following step by step in this tutorial: http://geezhawk.github.io/using-react-with-django-rest-framework

However, when I check the console in firefox I get the "Request failed with status code 500" message. The Django+React integration works fine, but for some reason it won't get the data. Any thoughts?

The code in the site is as follows:

Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Book

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author')
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Book
from .serializers import BookSerializer

class BookList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Book.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

index.html

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello React</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        {% render_bundle 'main' %}
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var BooksList = React.createClass({
    loadBooksFromServer: function(){
        axios.get(this.props.url)
        .then(function (data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this)
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadBooksFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadBooksFromServer, 
                    this.props.pollInterval)
    }, 
    render: function() {
        if (this.state.data) {
            console.log('DATA!')
            var bookNodes = this.state.data.map(function(book){
                return <li> {book.title} </li>
            })
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello React!</h1>
                <ul>
                    {bookNodes}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(<BooksList url='/api/' pollInterval={1000} />, 
    document.getElementById('container'))
```

Answer (score -1):

@somethingstrag i suggest you to test your API in postman before actually using it. can you give me information on how you registered urls?

```
this.props.url
```

please post the error you are getting. error code 500 means internal server error.